# How to split the result of Laravel paginator

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using the Laravel paginator on my site. I want to split the query result into 4 parts. Because my design has 2 rows of 3 items each and another 2 rows of 2 items each. So I can't use a single foreach loop for showing the items. In my controller, I have the below code.

```
$properties = Property::whereHas('createdBy', function ($query) {
            $query->where('enabled','=',true);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

And in my view, I am trying to split the result. I have tried `$properties->take(3)` and `$properties->chunk(3)`. But is not working.

Below is the content of paginator.
[image]

Please help.

Comment: try to `dd($properties)`, see how that object looked like. if i remember correctly, that object can't be chunked directly, you need to chunk its property instead.

Comment: What you mean by "split the result into 4 parts" ? I don't understand your question.

Comment: yeah, chunk that `items`, something like `$properties->items->chunk(4)`. i think you can figure out how to loop things from here.

Comment: @BagusTesa It is a protected property. I can't access it directly. I tried the methods `items()` and `getCollection()` as given here https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html. But both are returning empty items.

Comment: "_So I can't use a single foreach loop for showing the items_" Depending on your layout you _can_ use a single loop.

Comment: @brombeer How can I do that?

Comment: @BagusTesa Sorry, my mistake. I was looking at the different page count. It is working

Comment: Depends on the layout, as I said. Basically start a row, add your items, after X items close the row and start another, then after Y items close that row etc

Comment: @brombeer I am trying that only. Without chunking how can start over in the next loop at the correct index?

Comment: "_how can start over in the next loop at the correct index?_" What next loop? There will be only one loop. Sounds like BagusTesa's solution is working though, so use that